# How to set Columns beside each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting, upload

I am working on a Social Media Website.

html

```
<div class="col-8">

  
    {% if posts|length == 0 %}
      <span class="no-feed-text">
      <p>You need to follow someone to see their Posts<br>Meanwhile you can give look at your <a class="trending-page" href="{% url 'blog-trends' %}">Search</a> page</p>
      </span>
      <br><br>
    {% endif %}

    {% for post in posts %}

    
    <article class="content-section" style="overflow: auto;">
      
    
    
    


      <div class="mediacontent">
   {% if post.extension == '.mp4'%}
     <video loop class="video-context" width="500px" height="500px" controls>
            <source src="{{ post.file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
         </video>
   {% elif post.extension == '.jpg' or post.extension == '.jpeg' %}
  <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">
      <img class="image-context" src="{{ post.file.url }}">
    </a>
   {% endif %}
  </div>
  

  <a class="initials-modus" href="{% url 'profile-detail-view' post.author.pk %}">
  <div class="initials">
   <div class="media">
    <div class="img-cont3">
      <img class="rounded-circle article-img feed-pic" src="{{post.author.profile.image.url}}" alt="image">
      
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      
      
        <span class="mr-2 full-name-link">{{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}</span>
   
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
</a>








<script>
  var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
for(var i=0; i<videos.length; i++)
   videos[i].addEventListener('play', function(){pauseAll(this)}, true);


function pauseAll(elem){
    for(var i=0; i<videos.length; i++){
        //Is this the one we want to play?
        if(videos[i] == elem) continue;
        //Have we already played it && is it already paused?
        if(videos[i].played.length > 0 && !videos[i].paused){
        // Then pause it now
          videos[i].pause();
        }
    }
  }
</script>



<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-child one">
    <h3 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-child two">
    <p class="interactions">2.873.938 <span>Likes</span></p>
  </div>
  
</div>
        



    </article>

  
    {% endfor %}


    

    {% if posts.has_other_pages %}

      {% if posts.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{posts.previous_page_number}}">Previous</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% for num in posts.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if posts.number == num %}
          <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{num}}">{{num}}</a>
        {% elif num > posts.number|add:'-3' and num < posts.number|add:'3' %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{num}}">{{num}}</a>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if posts.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{posts.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{posts.paginator.num_pages}}">Last</a>
      {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The Posts are seperated in 2 Columns.

```
.col-8 {
  columns: 2;
}
```

That looks like that: [click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbuOj.png)

I want the Posts 2 to be next to Post 2, the latest Post should be next to the Post before.

I want it to be like that: [click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFlBl.png)

What should I put next to the columns code to get it like that?

Comment: You should include your relevant html in your post too.

Comment: I think the `columns` style attribute will always go "down" first; Bootstrap or using Flexbox make it pretty easy to go to the side first

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893686/css-columns-fill-row-first

Comment: No, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

for columns I would prefer to use css-grid and use grid-template-columns

example :

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="col-1" class="col">1</div>
   <div id="col-2" class="col">2</div>
   <div id="col-3" class="col">3</div>
   <div id="col-4" class="col">4</div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 500px;
}

.col {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: auto;
}

#col-1 {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

#col-2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#col-3 {
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
}

#col-4 {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

you can assign unique dimensions to each col as necessary and play with the container width and height

Comment: But I would have just one DIV and not Multiple 'col', because i just habe code to display uploaded Files.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean exactly, but say you were using a library like React, where you are using Components, you can still apply the CSS from the #container element to the child elements & it will still render the same way. You can change the values of grid-col-repeat to allow for more elements if necessary.